# clicking an icon with capybara

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, capybara

I have an icon:

```
 <i class="icon-edit" style="cursor: pointer;"></i>
```

That I have set a on click event in `jQuery`:

```
$( 'body' ).on( "click", ".icon-edit", function() { //code here });
```

Is there a way for me to click this icon in my `capybara` tests?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes.

```
Capybara.page.find('.icon-edit').click
```

The click method is on the Capybara::Node::Element, which `find` returns.  More information [here](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/jnicklas/capybara/master/Capybara/Node/Element#click-instance_method).

For quick answers, [here's a handy cheat sheet](https://gist.github.com/zhengjia/428105).

Comment: So when I run this with `type: :feature, js: true, slow: true` capybara cant find the css. I see it when i view page source on the test. Any ideas?

Comment: Sounds like test debugging :) It could be a lot of things. One thing is that Capybara can't find hidden elements, so it needs to be visible. I would also pause the test before the expectation, and look for the element with JQuery, and copy-paste the selector in to make sure there are no typos. You could also try changing the element from an <i> to a <p>, just to make sure it's visible to Capybara. But these things can take a while to find.